# xml file is created but not connected with java

Tags: java

I am working on my class project, I created a activity it shows the xml file name in java in red color it means error when i press alt+enter and trying to resolve the problem it says xml file is already created,its right but why my xml file is not connected with java.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teacherdashboard);
}
}
```

error is in this line .activity_teacherdashboard appears red.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_teacherdashboard);
```

Comment: what it means for you "connected with java", because I don't understand this part

Comment: thanks problem is solved by restarting the android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that `XML` file exists then please Restart Your `Android Studio`, that All